# Modify property value using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, foreach, where-clause

I have following classes:

```
public class QualifyResponse
{
    public Message[] MessageList{get; set;}
}

public class Message 
{
    public MessageDetail[] MessageDetailList{get; set;}
    public string MessageStatus{get; set;}
    public string ProviderCode{get; set;}
}

public partial class MessageDetail 
{
    public string MessageCategory{get; set;}
    public string MessageCode{get; set;}
    public string MessageSeverity{get; set;}
    public string MessageText{get; set;}
}
```

What I want is, For all the MessageDetailList, if the messageCode is equal to "status" then assign its messageText value to "Complete" after this query

I tried the following LINQ, but it didnt work i.e the MessageDetailList objects having MessageCode = "status" didn't have MessageText = "Complete".

```
response.MessageList.FirstOrDefault()
                    .MessageDetailList
                    .Where(message => message.MessageCode
                                             .ToLower()
                                             .Equals("status"))
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(status => 
                                { 
                                    status.MessageText = "Complete"; 
                                });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please clarify "it didn't work" : do you have an error ? (which message?) Or the expected status objects are simply not modified ?

Comment: If you have to update the values in the collection itself then you don't have to use ToList() method. Instead you can use your expression upto Where() method and then loop using foreach and updated.
If you don't have to update the values in the collection itself then you can use Select() after Where() and then use ToList().

Comment: @DragandDrop right, but the "new" list contains the same _references_, so setting `status.MessageText` should work. I suggest to use a debugger and see what's happening.

Comment: @DragandDrop Removing ToList() gives error `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<MessageDetail>' does not contain a definition for 'ForEach'`

Comment: It works fine [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FcwKdg) - what are you not showing us?

Comment: @Default create multiple objects of MessageDetail and check. Maybe its because of that

Comment: @RenéVogt, You re right, those are object not struct so the copy would have same reference. So It should works. And it's a no repro..

Comment: [stil works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0FIm0s). Please post a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of stalling and asking others to guess what's wrong.

Comment: May you give the result of `.MessageDetailList
                            .Where(message => message.MessageCode.ToLower() == "status").Count()` ?

Comment: @DragandDrop Count is 0. Means the Where condition is wrong :0

Comment: You could try the following: `message.MessageCode.ToLower().Equals("status", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)` This way any culture is ignored in the text comparison

Comment: @ThomasK doesnt work

Comment: obviously the `Where` fails to match the `"status"` string it could be due to a simple space in `MessageCode`. Try using `message.MessageCode.Trim().ToLower().Equals("status")` If this also fails. try this instead `message.MessageCode.ToLower().Contains("status")`

Comment: Is it because of the FirstOrDefault? As I can see that the first `MessageList` doesnt contain `message` object with `MessageCode` status

Comment: It's all legit from the look of things, you need to debug you app, break this up in to variables and check the result. Who knows it could be the setter or any number of external factors

Comment: Is this comming from entity framework?

Answer (score 0):

A bit of formatting helps read your code

However this should help and double check the results

> Note if your `Where` clause is correct it **WILL** update your
>   `MessageText` providing there isn't some funky setter going on

```
var message = response.MessageList.FirstOrDefault();
var messageDetails = message.MessageDetailList
                            .Where(message => message.MessageCode.ToLower() == "status")
                            .ToList();

messageDetails.ForEach(status => status.MessageText = "Complete");

messageDetails.ForEach(status => Debug.WriteLine(status.MessageText));
```

**Update**

This all should work fine

1. Try a `foreach` instead
2. Try putting a try catch around it all
3. Try checking the result immediately after you are setting it.
4. If this from Ef try `SaveChanges'

We don't know how you are checking your results

Comment: Isn't it the same query as mine? Whats the difference?

Comment: @HumaAli, do you get records after Where statement?

Comment: Yes, I do get records but the value remains the same, not modified

Comment: @HumaAli, The code you posted works fine. It does not reproduce the issue and the value is updated. I have tested the input you can see below.

Comment: var response = new QualifyResponse
    {
        MessageList = new Message[]
        {
            new Message()
            {
                MessageDetailList = new MessageDetail[]
                {
                    new MessageDetail(){
                        MessageCode="status",
                        MessageText="change me"
                    },
                    new MessageDetail(){
                        MessageCode="other",
                        MessageText="don't change me"
                    }
                } 
            }
        }
    };

Comment: Is it because of the FirstOrDefault? As I can see that the first MessageList doesnt contain message object with MessageCode status

Comment: First or default is fine